# Issue with multiple ALTER TABLE statements in a single transaction

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I'm having issues executing multiple `ALTER TABLE` statements in the same transaction, on MySQL **5.1.41**.  There is another developer running the same code and having none of these issues on **5.1.49**

Multiple `ADD FOREIGN KEY` statements on the same table work fine:

```
ALTER TABLE school_state ADD FOREIGN KEY (school_id) REFERENCES school(id) ON DELETE CASCADE; 
ALTER TABLE school_state ADD FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But across different tables, I get a cryptic error:

```
ALTER TABLE school_state ADD FOREIGN KEY (school_id) REFERENCES school(id) ON DELETE CASCADE; 
ALTER TABLE school_state ADD FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state(id) ON DELETE CASCADE; 
ALTER TABLE publisher_login ADD FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(id); 

Can't create table 'my_database.#sql-2cd_45' (errno: 150)
```

Stranger still, multiple `DROP FOREIGN KEY` statements fail even across the same table:

```
ALTER TABLE school_state DROP FOREIGN KEY school_state_ibfk_2; 
ALTER TABLE school_state DROP FOREIGN KEY school_state_ibfk_1; 

Error on rename of './my_database/school_state' to './my_database/#sql2-2cd-45' (errno: 152)
```

Am I really going to have to execute *each* single statement as its own transaction? Because that kind of defeats the purpose of having atomic transactions.

**UPDATE:** Per Ike's suggestion below, I've run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` after the `ADD FOREIGN KEY` query above and gotten the following:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
110630  8:01:12 Error in foreign key constraint of table my_database/#sql-2cd_95:
FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(id):
Cannot resolve column name close to:
) REFERENCES publisher(id)
```

Honestly, I still don't understand what the issue is, as the key it's referencing (`publisher.id`) does exist, and the field intended to become a foreign key (`publisher_login.publisher_id`) also very much exists. These statements run fine one at a time, so why are they causing errors when run all at once?

Answer (score 3):

DDL can't be rolled back, so you shouldn't be running it inside a transaction. You can read more about that in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cannot-roll-back.html).

As for the errors you are getting, you should run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and look at the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section to find out why it's failing.